# Two model forms in one view/template in Django using CBV

Tags: django, forms, view

Can someone show the example of usage of two model forms in one view/template?  The task is to process more than one form in one CBV, where model of the second form has FK to first form model, so value from select widget from first form must be processed as value for object, created in second form.

My forms looks like this:

```
class CompanyEditForm(ModelForm):
    name = CharField(label="Наименование", required=True)
    type = ModelChoiceField(queryset=CompanyTypes.objects.all(), label="Тип компании", empty_label=None, initial=3)
    description = CharField(label="Описание компании", required=False, widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 40, 'rows':3}))
    www = CharField(label="WEB сайт", required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Companies
        fields = ('type', 'name', 'description', 'www')


class BranchEditForm(ModelForm):
    name = CharField(label="Наименование офиса", required=True)
    type = ModelChoiceField(queryset=BranchTypes.objects.all(), label="Тип отделения", empty_label=None, initial=1)

    class Meta:
        model = Branches
        exclude = ('company', 'address')


class AddressEditForm(ModelForm):
    postalcode = IntegerField(label="Почтовый код", required=False)
    city = CharField(label="Город", required=True)
    street = CharField(label="Улица", required=True)
    app = CharField(label="Дом", required=True)
    app_extra = CharField(label="Корпус / Строение", required=False)
    comment = CharField(label="Примечание к адресу", required=False)
    exclude = ('company',)

    class Meta:
        model = Addresses
        fields = ('postalcode', 'city', 'street', 'app', 'app_extra', 'comment')
```

**UPDATE**

I wrote this mixin:

```
class MultiFormCreate(FormMixin, TemplateResponseMixin, View):
    formconf = None

    def get_form_classes(self):
        form_classes = {}
        for key, params in self.formconf.items():
            form_classes[key] = params.formclass
        return self.form_classes

    def get_initial(self, classname):
        inicial = {}
        if 'inicial' in self.formconf[classname]:
            inicial = self.formconf[classname]['inicial'].copy()
        return inicial

    def get_form_kwargs(self, classname):
        kwargs = {'initial': self.get_initial(classname), 'prefix': classname}
        if self.request.method in ('POST', 'PUT'):
            kwargs.update({
                'data': self.request.POST,
                'files': self.request.FILES,
                })
        return kwargs

    def get_forms(self):
        for classname, params in self.formconf.items():
            log.info("Name: %s, Params: %s" % (classname, params))
        return dict(
            [(classname, params['formclass'](**self.get_form_kwargs(classname))) for classname, params in self.formconf.items()])

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        forms = self.get_forms()
        return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(forms=forms))

    def get_success_url(self):
        if self.success_url:
            url = force_text(self.success_url)
        else:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured(
                "No URL to redirect to. Provide a success_url.")
        return url
```

then in a view i only need to write processing in post:

```
class CompanyCreate(MultiFormCreate):
    template_name = 'company/edit.html'
    success_url = '/forbidden/'
    formconf = {
        'company': {'formclass': CompanyEditForm, 'inicial': {'name': "TESTNAME"}},
        'branch': {'formclass': BranchEditForm},
        'address': {'formclass': AddressEditForm}
    }

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        forms = self.get_forms()
        cform = forms['company']
        aform = forms['address']
        bform = forms['branch']
        if cform.is_valid() and aform.is_valid() and bform.is_valid():
            ''' Creating main form form object (by saving tthe form) '''
            company_object = cform.save()
            ''' Creating dependant object '''
            address_object = aform.save(commit=False)
            branch_object = bform.save(commit=False)
            ''' assigning dependent fields '''
            address_object.company = company_object
            ''' saving dependent _object_ '''
            address_object.save()
            ''' managing another dependent fields '''
            branch_object.company = company_object
            branch_object.address = address_object
            ''' saving last object '''
            branch_object.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
        else:
            forms = self.get_forms()
            return self.render_to_response(self.get_context_data(forms=forms))
```

Comment: Are you trying to save branch form (BranchEditForm) in which company object should we passed as a object in it?

Comment: Yep! CompnayID of created object from CompanyForm must be in save results of BranchEditForm as 'company', if "Create" view, and if "Edit" view also..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code for view file :

```
    if request.method == "POST":
        company_form = CompanyEditForm(request.POST)
        if company_form.is_valid():
           company_object = company_form.save()
           post_data = request.POST.copy()
           branch_form = BranchEditForm(post_data)
           branch_form.data['company'] = company_object
           if branch_form.is_valid():
              branch_object.save()
```

rest implement your business logic ..